# Phoenix - no function clause matching in ProjWeb.UserController.sign_in/2

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

I have defined the following routes in
`router.ex`

```
    scope "/api/v1", ProjWeb do
        pipe_through :api

        post "/sign_up", UserController, :sign_up
        post "/sign_in", UserController, :sign_in

      end
```

Here is the controller actions

```
def sign_up(conn, %{"user" => user_params}) do
 # example code
 # response
end

def sign_in(conn, %{"user" => %{"email" => email, "password" => password}}) do  
 ### resp
end
```

`/api/v1/sign_up` works  with the following payload

```
{
    "user": {
        "email": "krishna@example.com",
        "name": "Krishna",
        "password": "SUPER_SECRET_PASS!"
    }
}
```

```
/api/v1/sign_in
```

with the following payload

```
{
    "user": {
        "email": "krishna@example.com",
        "password": "SUPER_SECRET_PASS!"
    }
}
```

Throws the following error

`no function clause matching in ProjWeb.UserController.sign_in/2`

Logs:

```
 # 1
   %Plug.Conn{adapter: {Plug.Cowboy.Conn, :...}, assigns: %{}, before_send:...}
   # 2
   %{}
```

Comment: How are you sending this? Do you have the proper header to let Phoenix know to expect json? `Content-Type: application/json`

Comment: @JustinWood thanks ! , I was using postman to create the request and instead of setting ```Content-Type: application/json ``` I was sending ```Content-Type: application/javascript```  . would be happy to accept an answer if you post it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you have the wrong `Content-Type` header set. You will need to make sure you are sending `Content-Type: application/json` in order for Phoenix to know that you are sending JSON information.

Answer (score 2):

Your payload doesn't seem to come through correctly, since the second argument you pass is an empty map (see logs). Since your `sign_in` function expects a struct with a `user` key, it cannot match your call.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I have posted in the question the payload I am sending..

Comment: I see, but Phoenix doesn't recognize it. Try adding a function `def sign_in(conn, %{})` and you'll see that this function _will_ match. This then means your params are not parsed correctly